# Make text stand still when resizing window

Tags: html, css

Sorry for bad title but couldn't think of anything better.

[image]

I have this progress bar created with Bootstrap, and images and paragraphs oer and under. But when I try to resize the window (lower it), it changes positions and suddenly wrecks everything. I need it the imgs and paragraphs to stand exactly same positions as the width of the progress bar.

[image]

```
<div>
    <p style="display:inline-block;">0</p>
    <p style="margin-left:23.6%;display:inline-block;">800</p>
    <p style="margin-left:1.9%;display:inline-block;">950</p>
    <p style="margin-left:1.9%;display:inline-block;">1100</p>
    <p style="margin-left:1.9%;display:inline-block;">1250</p>
    <p style="margin-left:1.9%;display:inline-block;">1400</p>
    <p style="margin-left:1.9%;display:inline-block;">1550</p>
    <p style="margin-left:1.9%;display:inline-block;">1700</p>
    <p style="margin-left:1.9%;display:inline-block;">1850</p>
    <p style="margin-left:1.9%;display:inline-block;">2000</p>
</div>
<div class="row" style="text-align:center;margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;">
    <div class="progress" style="margin-bottom:0px;height:40px;background-color:#cfcfcf;">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="'@ViewBag.EloWidth'"
             aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="3000" style="width:@ViewBag.EloWidth%;background-color:#6378ff;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="/Images/lvl1.png">
    <img src="/Images/lvl2.png" style="margin-left:21%;">
    <img src="/Images/lvl3.png" style="margin-left:1.3%;">
    <img src="/Images/lvl4.png" style="margin-left:1.9%;">
    <img src="/Images/lvl5.png" style="margin-left:2.2%;">
    <img src="/Images/lvl6.png" style="margin-left:2.3%;">
    <img src="/Images/lvl7.png" style="margin-left:2.3%;">
    <img src="/Images/lvl8.png" style="margin-left:2.3%;">
    <img src="/Images/lvl9.png" style="margin-left:2.3%;">
    <img src="/Images/lvl10.png" style="margin-left:2.3%;">
</div>
```

Comment: You don't see to be using any of the Bottstrap helper classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using bootstrap for the rest of your layout (the labels and icons). Try this one:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <p>0</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
        <p>800</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
        <p>950</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
        <p>1100</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
        <p>1250</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
        <p>1400</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
        <p>1550</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
        <p>1700</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
        <p>1850</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
        <p>2000</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="text-align:center;margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;">
    <div class="progress col-12" style="margin-bottom:0px;height:40px;background-color:#cfcfcf;">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="'@ViewBag.EloWidth'"
             aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="3000" style="width:@ViewBag.EloWidth%;background-color:#6378ff;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <img src="/Images/lvl1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
        <img src="/Images/lvl2.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
        <img src="/Images/lvl3.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
        <img src="/Images/lvl4.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
        <img src="/Images/lvl5.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
        <img src="/Images/lvl6.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
        <img src="/Images/lvl7.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
        <img src="/Images/lvl8.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
        <img src="/Images/lvl9.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
        <img src="/Images/lvl10.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a helpful guild about the [Bootstrap Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/). You might also use a `class="col-12"` for your progress bar.

EDIT: Working Plunker for Bootstrap4:
[Plunker BS 4](https://plnkr.co/edit/k0bCDFyeItfWOcdmI5h9?p=preview)

EDIT2: Working Plunker for Bootstrap3:
[Plunker BS 3](https://plnkr.co/edit/UMcDCMSax2FftzGLf7Ce?p=preview)

Comment: I'm not sure you setup bootstrap correct. Are you using a `class="container"` around your layout?

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap do you use?

Comment: Yes, <div class="container body-content"> around it

Comment: I'm using version 3

Comment: I've added a Plunker for BS4, give me another minute for BS3 (not really used to it)

Comment: I've added another Plunker for BS3.3.7. Obviously, there is no difference.